# Caching data in PHP

Tags: php, caching

I'm developing a site in PHP which has some complex SQL queries and I would like to implement a caching feature to reduce the load on the database.

I'm just wondering would it be better to write and read HTML directly to a file or perhaps create something like a YAML file with a delimiter to separate records then wrap it in HTML with a function?

My thinking is that this would allow user options (for example, number of records to display) to be applied to the request.

Any advice / suggestions appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use any of these for caching backends:

- http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php
- http://memcached.org/
- http://xcache.lighttpd.net/

and use Zend_Cache for a unified interface to them

- http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.cache.html

Whether to use full page caching or partial caching depends on your specific UseCases. Usually, your application will have a mix of both.

Answer (score 1):

Although I've never personally used it before, there is a PEAR [package](http://pear.php.net/package/Cache) for caching. Consider it amongst other options like Zend_Cache.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement caching on multiple places in your application:

- you can implement conditional GET (ETag and Last-Modified HTTP headers)
- do data caching with the mentioned solutions ([Cache_Lite](http://pear.php.net/package/Cache_Lite), [Zend_Cache](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.cache.html), [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php)) with multiple backends (file, [memcached](http://memcached.org/), shared memory)
- you can cache the template files as you said ([Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/))

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at Zend Cache
http://framework.zend.com/manual/de/zend.cache.html

I usually store the result of the SQL queries somewhere (depending on what you are looking for, i.e. sometimes is caching it in $_SESSION ok (user related data), sometimes it's not (big resultsets for not user dependant queries) and then my class just checks if the cache exists and continues accordingly.