# Is this a good way to cache data in PHP?

Tags: php, caching

I've figured out a way to cache data (so that I won't have to re-access the database when the same data has already been fetched before), and I do it by using a static variable inside a function:

```
function get_user( $id, $flush=false ){
    static $cache;
    if ( isset($cache[$id]) && !$flush )
        return $cache[$id];
    // Do something here to get user information
    $user_info = $value;
    // Return value after storing data into cache
    return $cache[$id] = $user_info;
}
```

I'm not really sure if this is a good idea or maybe there's a better way to do caching. Is this a fine method or not? If not, then what are the disadvantages?

Comment: Are you trying to cache pages like template engines do? Or just peices of data? Because it look's like you want to cache data based on each user.

Comment: The pattern you are looking for is "[identity map](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/identityMap.html)" "An Identity Map keeps a record of all objects that have been read from the database in a single business transaction. Whenever you want an object, you check the Identity Map first to see if you already have it."

Comment: This cannot be answered until you define 'before' and 'good' or 'fine'. By 'before', I mean to point out that this data will only live for the current request. That way it's pretty useless, since your database will most probably also cache this data, thereby rendering your cache function pretty much useless while adding another source of potential error. So you might want to look into existing cache mechanisms like [memcached](http://memcached.org/), which are at least as 'good' or 'fine' as your solution, with a larger user base and most probably less issues than your own implementation.

Comment: Are you speaking about cache during the life time of the script, or are you talking about cache as in multiple call to the server. Unless you are setting session variable and using PHP caching, Not sure how you are able to main $cache the next time the script is call.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Caching data in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160901/caching-data-in-php)

Comment: i'm only referring to caching upon a single request.. in most cases, I have to actually look-up a certain information multiple times (not just user information, sometimes large data which often does MySQL queries involving multiple tables and rows).. so I figured out a solution above to avoid re-querying from the database.. 

"Good/Fine" if it doesn't create any further problems and if it's an acceptable optimization technique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look [here](http://simas.posterous.com/php-data-caching-techniques). There are several solutions described. The type of the cache depents on how long you need to cache the data. Static variables are not shared between PHP processes and only can be cached for a short time – spanning script execution lifetime.

Comment: **Static scope variables**: simple, only cache a single execucion multiple request
 **Apc shared memory functions**:  need to restart server to force delete all cache data, need to install apc
 **memcache**: need server, not trivial code
in memory databases: need to build around it, size limits, still hiting the database
 **files**: good web the data is huge chunks of static content, can be serverd by other databases/mirrored, not valid for small chunks of data (the id of name 'fred' in table users).

Comment: yes, I'm aware of static variables only available in a single execution.. and I'm only referring to a solution where I need to cache data in a single execution.. I usually need to access data from the database not just once, and when I meant data, they're large.. I'm worried that I'll have to do redundant queries several times and it would 'cause the page to load a little bit delayed.. Thanks for your response..

Comment: As @Koen stated, the link no longer works, however the wayback machine has an old copy - https://web.archive.org/web/20130411030614/http://simas.posterous.com/php-data-caching-techniques

Answer (score 3):

Your code is a good place to start in the sense that it will do the job (more or less -- `array_key_exists` would be a better choice than `isset` here, and you are not initializing the array explicitly).

The disadvantages of such a simple approach will start to become evident as you evolve your code and start needing more functionality to your caching layer. A whole array of problems is going to stem from the fact that your backing store cannot be accessed outside of the `get_user` function. It would be much better to package the caching utility into a class so that you can later have multiple operations that modify the backing store. In its most basic form this would look like

```
class Cache {
    private $store = array();

    public function get($key, $flush = false) {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

A further improvement would be to abstract your backing store (e.g. into an `ICacheBackingStore` interface) so that you can plug in and configure the backing store for your cache dynamically (lots of options here -- storing in database, serialized files, session, memcached or similar). For example:

```
interface ICacheBackingStore {
    function exists($key);
    function get($key);
    function set($key, $value);
    function purge($key);

    function getAllKeys();
}

class ArrayBackingStore implements ICacheBackingStore {
    private $store = array();

    public function exists($key) {
        return array_key_exists($this->store, $key);
    }

    // etc
}

class Cache {
    // you can now change/configure how the cache works through one line of code
    private $store = new ArrayBackingStore;

    public function set($key) {
        return $store->get($key);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, array_key_exists() didn't work since it's expecting an array.. Also, wouldn't isset() be a bit faster than array_key_exists()?

Thanks for the input about implementing a separate class for the cache utility.. Now, how can this be accessed if I need it in a certain function call?

Comment: I mean, I would need to create an instance for this class right? So that means, I would need to access this utility be declaring an instance through a global variable? Or it's OK to access it like this?: Cache::get( $id )

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested anything for you, but I'm sure you could get this to work. But a fine method? not really as far as I know.

Basically, you have two options: 'caching' within one run of a script, or longer caching.

This code only works on your current session/file/script, so it's scope is limited. If you have certain data you need to get, you should probably just have some models that you save to a variable. 
You allready should know what models you need (or you can find out during the running of your script) and you can just load once, access multiple times. I don't see the need of a special "one script/session only cache"?

on the other hand, if you want to cache for a longer time, multiple requests etc, you should use something like `memcached` or `APC`. These have easy to use PHP methods and help you store stuff that is too expensive to keep on reading from your database

Answer (score 0):

You can use file cache or memcache, apc. Zend has good cache lib called Zend_Cache it supports many backends like file, memcache, apc. So if you use that you can configure the cache based on client needs, without recoding.